# Does Greenplum support Kerberos Authentication between its nodes?

Tags: kerberos, greenplum

I need to "kerberize" our Greenplum cluster.  One of the aspects of this is that I should kerberize the interface between the GP master and its Segment Hosts.  I have been unable to determine if this is supported or not.

I have seen the parameters in the posgresql.conf file (krb_server_keyfile and krb_srvname) and have tried to set these, but it does not seem to work (Greenplum still works, it just does not appear the connection is kerberized).

I did this with hadoop and it was pretty straight forward, but, again, cannot figure out how to do it in GP or if it is even possible.  Any ideas?

Thanks

Comment: Why would you want to kerberize a GP cluster?

Comment: The point of kerberos is to secure and lockdown access between servers.  GP runs across several.  I am hoping Kerberos can be used to prevent a man-in-the-middle-attack.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So... the answer, as near as I can tell is this:

First, for clarification, there are two places where I am required to "kerberize" GP.  The first in master/slave connectivity.  This turned out the be easy enough after I learned this communication is ssh based.  I just switched the rsa/dsa generated passwordless authorization with Kerberos SSH.  I am not sure this is really any more or less secure, but a requirement none-the-less.  The second is locking down the administrative/jdbc access.  This should easy, after all GP is based upon Postgres, I have have secured Postgres with Kerberos in the past.  Unfortuntaly, GP is based upon Postgres 8.2.  This was before GSS support for Kerberos was added to Postgres, and I cannot get this to work.  I am not positive that it can.  Maybe GP will upgrade to 8.4 (at a minimum) soon and I can try that.

Answer (score 0):

Refer to [Greenplum HD Manager 1.2 Installation and User Guide](http://www.greenplum.com/sites/default/files/gp_gphd_1_2_0_3_gphdmanager_iug_ga.pdf) for instructions on how to deploy Kerberos. The document is related to Hadoop, but should serve for a general Greenplum install.

Comment: Thanks John,  however, I don't think this is really what I am looking for. These directions lockdown the GPHD (Greenplum Hadoop). And when followed will result in a secure, "kerberized" Hadoop implementation. What these directions do not seem to include is the ability to secure Greenplum itself. I don't know GP very well, so maybe I am missing the boat, but GP has several nodes that all talk to each other, right?  This is independent of Hadoop, right?  It is that communication that needs to be locked down. When the GP master sends something to one of the Segment hosts, how is that secured?

Comment: Internode communications on the Greenplum is managed via SSH and access restrictions between the nodes in the pg_hba.conf file. The database nodes shouldn't even allow regular users to log on in an ideal situation.

Comment: hhmmm I will play with that a bit.  Based upon the header documentation, I thought that file (pg_hba.conf) only governed client connections and not internode connections.  Will check that out and reply back.   I appreciate you thoughts on this topic.

Comment: I cannot get kerberos to work that way.  My pg_hba file does not even have references to other nodes on the GP cluster... so I am not sure how that file can be used for internode communication.  Have tried many different things with that file... with no success.

Comment: The lack of references to other nodes is odd. Did you roll your own for the GP cluster or did you uy a DCA?

Comment: Rolled our own.  I am wondering if ssh is the answer here.  Doesn't GP do all its internode comms via ssh, via keyless ssh?  If so, maybe I can just switch the ssh method from rsa/dsa to kerberos.  I will try this next.